# score ninja adapter API

Tags: android

hey all,
i have build a game in android. and to put in the score section i am using the score ninja adapter API. i have done all the things told on the score ninja website but every time i tries to show the score card . it tells me that "Sorry,there was a problem loading the score card".
the method i am using is
scoreNinjaAdapter.show(200); 
here i have put 200 as an arbitrary score and i am supposing that it should work but it never seems to work otherwise there is no error or exception.
can any body help me out or show me some kind of example ..
i am totally stuck here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was curious about ScoreNinja, so I took a quick look at this problem.  Looking at the ScoreNinja source, the message "Sorry,there was a problem loading the score card", will show up if the score adapter can't fetch your scores.  I put together a quick example and the only way I was able to make this happen was by providing a bad ID and Private Key to the ScoreNinjaAdapter constructor.

If you are still looking for an example, here is my code 
https://gist.github.com/815227

Comment: thanx for the example, it was really helpful but after entering the score you never seem to get it in the global highscore chart. every time the global highscore opens and shows no previous score...          do u have any clue about that?

Comment: Thanx for the example and about score not showing, it seems to show after 3 to 4 hours. i do not know why the delay but atleast its working :) thanx again